# filter search results while loop to custom field names

Tags: php, wordpress

If I can filter search results based on post_type

at:                         `if ($post->post_type == "mobile-experience") { ?>`

How can I add two more filters that will filter results based on custom field name

I have tried:

```
if ($post->post_meta == "mobile_app") { ?>
```

But does not work.

Custom field name is '`Mobile App`'.

I want to display search results under 3 custom field names; nothing works.

```
<?php
// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

if ($post->post_type == "mobile-experience") { ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'search-mobile-experience'); // works
    }

if ($post->post_meta == "mobile_app") { ?> // Doesn't work

        <?php get_template_part( 'new-mobile-app_template');
}
else { ?>
```

**Update: Thursday 1:15PM ($#&!!)**

Thanks so much for the advice guys; this is driving me nuts. Below is what I currently have. But still appears my **custom field filter is being ignored.**

```
        <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                if ($post->post_type == "mobile-experience") { ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'search-mobile-experience');
                    }

            if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mobile_app', true) == "mobile_app") { ?> 

                <?php get_template_part( 'new-mobile-app-template');
                        }
                    else { ?>

                        <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                    }
            endwhile;

        else :
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
```

*Then I have 2 templates:*

```
new-mobile-app-template.php
```

and

```
search-mobile-experience.php
```

*(eventually I will have one for the third, or custom field filter 2)*

Both looking like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content. Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <p>Mobile Website | March 28, 2014 </p>
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>

        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                        <?php if ((get_custom_field('Objective')) !== ''): ?>
                            <?php print_custom_field('Objective'); ?>
                        <?php endif ?> 

        </div>
    </article>
    <!-- #post --><hr />
```

My objective is to have a Search results page with 3 categories:

---

**Articles (All posts and pages except 2 below mentioned custom fields)**

{ Search Results }

---

**Custom Field #1**

{ Search Results }

---

**Custom Field #2**

{ Search Results }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)? Something like:

```
<?php
// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

if ($post->post_type == "mobile-experience") { ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'search-mobile-experience'); // works
    }

if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mobile_app', true) == "mobile_app") { ?> 

        <?php get_template_part( 'new-mobile-app_template');
}
else { ?>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks awesome, but still didn't work; I have updated my question, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Mevius' answer is correct. In addition, to check for meta regardless of the value:

```
if( '' != get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mobile_app', true ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: How does `update_post_meta()` handle "blank" values, when a post is saved in the admin? I haven't checked. Would it be an empty string? False? Null? Blank? I have no clue, actually. That would definitely effect whether or not `'' !=` would work at all times.

Comment: May be better off checking `!empty()`

Comment: From the codex entry for `get_post_meta()`: "If there is nothing to return the function will return an empty array unless `$single` has been set to `true`, in which case an empty string is returned."